# What is the best way to implement a sql for retrieving multiple user names from same query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a products table where I include 3 columns, created_user_id, updated_user_id and in_charge_user_id, all of which are related to my user table, where I store the id and name of the users.

I want to build an efficient query to obtain the names of the corresponding user_id's.

The query that I build so far is the following:

```
SELECT products.*, 
(SELECT name FROM user WHERE user_id = products.created_user_id) as created_user,
(SELECT name FROM user WHERE user_id = products.updated_user_id) as updated_user,
(SELECT name FROM user WHERE user_id = products.in_charge_user_id) as in_charge_user
 FROM products
```

The problem with this query is that if I have 30,000 records, I am executing 3 more queries per row.

What would be a more efficient way of achieving this? I am using mysql.

Comment: I think your query is wrong, created_user_id are in products table, not in users table, right?

Comment: @DanFromGermany yes you are right, I fixed it, how would you do such a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each type of user id (created, updated, in_charge) you would JOIN the users table once:

```
SELECT
  products.*,
  u1.username AS created_username,
  u2.username AS updated_username,,
  u3.username AS in_charge_username,
FROM products
JOIN user u1 ON products.created_user_id = u1.user_id
JOIN user u2 ON products.updated_user_id = u2.user_id
LEFT JOIN user u3 ON products.in_charge_user_id = u3.user_id
```

This is the best practice method to obtain the data.
It is similiar to your query with sub-selects but a more modern approach which I think the database can optimize and utilize better.

**Important:**

You need foreign key index on all the user_id fields in both tables! 
Then the query will be very fast no matter how many rows are in the table. This requires an engine which supports foreign keys, like `InnoDB`.

`LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` ?

As the other answers suggest a `LEFT JOIN`, I would not do a left join.
If you have an user id in the products table, there *MUST* be a linked user_id in the user table, except for the in_charge_user which is only present some times. If not, the data would be semantically corrupt. The foreign keys assure that you always have a linked user_id and a user_id can only be deleted when there is no linked product left.
`JOIN` is equivalent to `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: created_user_id and updated_user_id are always set, but in_charge_user_id sometimes is null. Would it not be better to user LEFT JOIN for in_charge_user_id?

Comment: @BernardWiesner yes exactly!

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT JOIN instead of subselects.

Your query should be like:

```
SELECT 
    P.*,
    [CU].[name],
    [UU].[name],
    [CU].[name]
FROM products AS [P]
    LEFT JOIN user AS [CU] ON [CU].[user_id] = [P].[created_user_id]
    LEFT JOIN user AS [UU] ON [UU].[user_id] = [P].[updated_user_id]
    LEFT JOIN user AS [CU] ON [CU].[user_id] = [P].[in_charge_user_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your query should be fine.  You only need an index on `user(user_id)` or better yet `user(user_id, name)` for performance.  I imagine that the first exists.

Second, you can write this using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.*, uc.name as created_user,
       uu.name as updated_user, uin.name as in_charge_user
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     user uc
     ON uc.user_id = p.created_user_id LEFT JOIN
     user uu
     ON uu.user_id = p.updated_user_id LEFT JOIN
     user uin
     ON uin.user_id = p.in_charge_user_id;
```

With one of the above indexes, the two methods should have very similar performance.

Also note the use of `LEFT JOIN`.  This handles the case where one or more of the user ids is missing.

Comment: what is the reason you use LEFT JOIN instead of using INNER JOIN?

Comment: @BernardWiesner . . . The answer explains this.  All the rows in `products` are still returned, even when there are no matches on one or more of the fields.

Comment: when you refer to the two methods, do you mean the example I gave (using inner queries) compared to the example you gave (using joins)?

Comment: @BernardWiesner . . . Your query has correlated subqueries.  Although this is a type of `join`, it is usually distinguished from explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below query

```
SELECT products.*, c.name as created_user,u.name as updated_user,i.name as in_charge_user
FROM products left join user c on(products.created_user_id=c.user_id ) left join user u on(products.updated_user_id=u.user_id ) left join user u on(products.in_charge_user_id=i.user_id )
```

Also as Gordon Linoff mentioned create index on user table will fetch your data faster.